# Gostaria de saber como listar dados em tabelas diferentes do bootstrap usando Codeigniter

Tags: html5, codeigniter

Esta é a view com nome de dashboard.php

```
<main role="main" class="col-md-10 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
<div style="top:-5px" class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <th style="background:#585858; color:white" colspan="2">Regs para Remover Hoje:</th>
                    <th style="background:#585858; color:white"><?php $matricula = date ("d-m-Y");echo"<input style='background:#585858; color:white; border:none; text-align:center' type='text' value='$matricula'";?> </th>
                        <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px;">Nome</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID Unico do TS</th>
                        </tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($cadastros as $cad){?>
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px; text-align:left"><?= $cad->nick; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id_unico; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <th style="background:#585858; color:white" colspan="3">Registros não Removidos</th>
                        <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px;">Nome</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID Unico do TS</th>
                        </tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($cadastros as $cad){?>
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px; text-align:left"><?= $cad->nick; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id_unico; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

E esse é o controller com nome de estatisticas.php

```
public function index($indice=null)
{
    $this->verificar_sessao();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('data_vencimento =', date('Y-m-d'));
    $dados['cadastros'] = $this->db->get('cadastro')->result();
    $this->load->view('includes/html_header');
    $this->load->view('includes/menu');

    $this->load->view('dashboard',$dados);
    $this->load->view('includes/html_footer');
}
```

Aee fica assim
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogG49.png

gostaria de saber se tem como a primeira tabela eu listar os registos igual a data ali acima 07/04/2019, como ja esta e na segunda tabela lista somente registros anterior a essa data 07/04/2019.

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma que você elaborou, não dará certo. Há um erro também em relação ao seu controller. Se você está trabalhando com MVC, acredito que você deva inserir a function de retorno de registro dentro do model. Ao meu ver, ficaria dessa forma:

## Controller - estatisticas.php

```
public function index($indice=null)
{
    $this->verificar_sessao();
    $this->load->model('estatisticas_model');

    $dados['cadastros_atual'] = $this->estatisticas_model->get_estatisticas('atual'); // data atual
    $dados['cadastros_anterior'] = $this->estatisticas_model->get_estatisticas('anterior'); // data anterior

    $this->load->view('includes/html_header');
    $this->load->view('includes/menu');

    $this->load->view('dashboard',$dados);
    $this->load->view('includes/html_footer');
}
```

## Model - estatisticas_model.php

```
public function get_estatisticas($tipo=null){
    if($tipo){
        switch($tipo){
            case 'atual':
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->where('data_vencimento =', date('Y-m-d'));
                $result = $this->db->get('cadastro')->result();         
            break; 

            case 'anterior':
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->where('data_vencimento <=', date('Y-m-d'));
                $result = $this->db->get('cadastro')->result();         
            break;          
        }

        return $result;
    } else {
        return "Nenhum tipo registrado.";
    }
}
```

## View - estatisticas.php

```
<main role="main" class="col-md-10 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
<div style="top:-5px" class="col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <th style="background:#585858; color:white" colspan="2">Regs para Remover Hoje (atual)</th>
                    <th style="background:#585858; color:white"><?php $matricula = date ("d-m-Y");echo"<input style='background:#585858; color:white; border:none; text-align:center' type='text' value='$matricula'";?> </th>
                        <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px;">Nome</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID Unico do TS</th>
                        </tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($cadastros_atual as $cad){?>
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px; text-align:left"><?= $cad->nick; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id_unico; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <th style="background:#585858; color:white" colspan="3">Registros não Removidos (anterior)</th>
                        <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px;">Nome</th>
                            <th style="padding:5px">ID Unico do TS</th>
                        </tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($cadastros_anterior as $cad){?>
                <tr style="text-align:center; font-size:12pt">
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px; text-align:left"><?= $cad->nick; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:5px"><?= $cad->id_unico; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sou novo em Codeigniter mano, por enquanto estou usando apenas as Views e Controllers, nao cheguei a usar as Models, mas irei ver como funciona e implementar seu codigo aqui. obrigado desde ja.